# JButton interfering with mouse listener on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, mouseevent, jbutton

I have a `JPanel` with a mouse listener that checks for `mouseEntered` and `mouseExited`, this works perfectly apart form the fact that the mouse focuses to a button on the pane and triggers the `mouseExited` event.

Is there a setting to make a button not take the mouse's focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never needed to specifically modify the focus in this type of scenario.  Nor am I familiar with a JPane so I presumed you mean JPanel.

```java
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class FocusDemo {
       private JPanel  panel;
       private JButton button1;

       JFrame          frame = new JFrame("TempWindow");

       private FocusDemo() {
          panel = new JPanel();
          button1 = new JButton("Button");
          button1.addActionListener((ae) -> System.out.println("button pressed"));
          panel.add(button1);
          MyMouseListener ml = new MyMouseListener();
          panel.addMouseListener(ml);
          panel.addMouseMotionListener(ml);
          frame.add(panel);

       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
          SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new FocusDemo().start());
       }

       public void start() {
          frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // this line set the window in the
                                             // center of the screen
          frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          frame.pack();
          frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
          frame.setVisible(true);

       }

       private class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
          public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
             System.out.println("mouse entered");
          }

          public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {
             System.out.println("mouse exited");
          }
       }

    }
```